# rails server to server image transfers with heroku's local file system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm creating a webservice to grab a bunch of images from external sites the user specifies and store them on S3.

The app is hosted on heroku.

Flow for the heroku app:
1. calls out to www.example.com/image.jpg and saves file locally
2. processes the image into different sizes
3. uploads the image to S3

I'm concerned about heroku's [ephemeral file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos). I'll just be using it as a /tmp store, but I'm worried about running into limits with it. If the users were uploading from their local machines then I could do direct to S3 uploads, but since it's from another server I don't see a way.

**Has anyone experience issues with heroku's temp local file system while trying to process lots of files?**

Comment: Have **you** experienced any issues while doing this or are you just looking for other peoples' experiences before you implement this? Also, can you define "lots"?

Comment: i have not experience issues. looking for other people experiences. not sure how many yet, it's less about scale and more about reliability of the ephemeral file system on heroku. if i'm doing 1000s of images per minute i can always ad more dynos, but if 10% of the time the local file storage craps out then it's not viable

Comment: I think if you are doing 1000s of images per minute consistently and you don't want to risk losing any images, you'd definitely want to store the images in some reliable place as you work through your queue. The filesystem in Heroku isn't guaranteed to be there very long, period.

Answer (score 1):

With PaperClip, you have the option of providing a remote_url for your image. You could still upload direct to S3 and avoid the risk of using the Heroku filesystem.

Comment: do you happen to know if this does all the processing in memory? or does it need to use /tmp storage so that imagemagick can operate on it? thx for the feedback!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about the ImageMagick implementation at Heroku but since the resize-and-upload-to-S3 setup worked prior to the ephemeral filesystem, I would guess that it's either in memory or Heroku provides the required privileges to ImageMagick to create a reliable local copy. They do recommend saving the original to S3 first, and then using background workers for the image processing so that dynos aren't tied up, impacting the end-user experience.